# Writing crystal direction of negative numbers using Latex interpreter

Tags: matlab, latex

I am using the latex interpreter to write crystal directions. I have the below code:

```
ax = gca;
ax.ThetaAxis.TickLabelInterpreter = 'latex';
ax.ThetaTickLabel = {'[2$\overline{1}\overline{1}$0]...
```

But if I use this, I get the direction `[2110]` and the lines above the two 1's are connected. The reason this is not good is because it could be interpreted as `2 -11 0` but it needs to be interpreted as `2 -1 -1 0`. Note the `-` will be above the `1` as I have below.

How can I have the lines above two 1's not connected? I also do not want to add a space between the numbers as the spacing would look weird. I just want smaller lines above the numbers.

Comment: Btw what is *Python interpreter*? Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, typo, meant Latex interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\bar` instead of `\overline` like this:

```
ax.ThetaTickLabel = {'[2$\bar{1}\bar{1}$0]...
```

But if you want to stick to `\overline` you can do either of the following:

Add a *thinspace* in between like this:

```
ax.ThetaTickLabel = {'[2$\overline{1} \thinspace \overline{1}$0]...
```

or you can introduce a space of desired length as follows:

```
ax.ThetaTickLabel = {'[2$\overline{1} \hspace*{0.5mm} \overline{1}$0]...  
%Change the space size according to your need
```

Comment: Interesting...is there a way to make a bit thinner than that? The thinspace still adds a little too much space, but if I could just ever slightly reduce it, it would be perfect